# Is this a 4R9 resistor or somthing else?

Tags: resistors, components, colour-coding

After a power-peak due to a broken main electricity cable, me and my neigbours got some broken devices.

At our house only my motor cycle trickle chargers were connected. And all 3 got broken :(. Since they are rather new and not insured, I would see of I can repair them.

It looks like a resistor(like) component is broken. This component is twice as big as a normal resistor (and smaller than a e.g. a 5W power resistor) and has a color coding I am not sure of. I see Yellow, Grey (or Black, not well to see) Brown/Gold(?? - there is a glitter in it), Gold.

Is this a 4,9 Ohms resitor? Or something else? It is in the beginning of the circuit, just after the 230V AC. The first component is covered with the black wrap and seems to be good (at least, if it should be 0 ohms). Than this resistor(?) comes.

The unit:

[image: photo1]

The resistor:

[image: photo2]

The back side of the board where the resistor was soldered:

[image: photo3]

I was not able to place the sharp detail images here, uploaded them at:

[original images](https://we.tl/t-uaIsuCHKsx)

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Should still be able to measure the resistance, can you not?

Comment: somewhat related: [How to make an educated guess about power ratings of common throughole resistors when datasheet is not available](https://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-guess-power-rating-of-throughole-resistors.html)

Comment: Thxs  when I measure it, it is ‘unlimited’ high resistance, no currence at all. So it really seems broken.

Comment: yellow black brown gold is what I see. 400 ohms 1%. But that is an odd value (not in E12) so probably it's 470.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess at a 47 ohm (the violet band would be right over the hottest part of the body, so prone to discoloration). The resistor is on the mains input side of the board, upstream of the voltage suppressor (RV1) so is likely a fusible type intended to fail reliably open circuit with  the suppressor clamps the input down. As such you're not likely to be able to measure it.

[Here's](http://www.vishay.com/docs/28737/nfr25.pdf)  A possible match from Vishay.

Comment: Thxs. This sounds logical, since it failed at the peak-power. Is this also the ‘fuse’ mentioned in the print at the back of the board?  If it was OK, I should be able to measure something with my ohms meter? Now it gives no measurement at all..

Comment: I'd say yes. What are the two wires that connect to the board either side of the "CAUTION:" note? I can't see the designation of the device connected there, but it's also in the series path.

Comment: The 2 bigger holes in the top hold de 230V AC wires. The 2 little holes next to “For continued” hold the (suppost) broken resistor, which is indeed in series path with the 230V AC.